# Zero derivative implies prime power

Tags: abstract-algebra

Over the integers mod p, how do we show that f' = 0 if and only if $f = g^p$ for some polynomial g?

Comment: The direction $\Leftarrow$ is pretty straightforward: by the chain rule, $f'=pg^{p-1}g'=0\pmod{p}$

Answer (score 2):

Write $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$. Then $f'(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n i a_i x^{i-1}$. If we have $f'$ is the zero polynomial, this implies that $i a_i \equiv 0 \mod p$. Thus the only powers of $x$ with non-zero coefficients are the ones divisible by $p$. But then you can write
$ f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^m a_{ip} x^{ip} = \left(\sum_{i=0}^m b_i x^i \right)^p$, with $b_i^p = a_{ip}$. Here we have used the fact that the Frobenius automorphism is an automorphism.

So let $g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^m b_i x^i$, and you have $f = g^p$. For the other direction, just use Matt's comment.